# iconUrl in agm markers

Tags: html, angular, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to incorporate the iconUrl property in my agm map. However when I do I get this response and I do not understand why.[image]

```
<agm-marker [latitude] = "currentLat" [longitude]= "currentLng" 
[iconUrl]= "../../assets/images/polkaDots.jpg" >

    <!-- Marker info -->
    <agm-info-window>
        <h3>You are here</h3>
        <button>I am interested</button>

    </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove square brackets from iconUrl attribute